# How to phrase this logic?

Tags: javascript

I want to compare multiple forms of a person's name. The hierarchy of consideration is:

last name > first name > middle name,

with full spelling > initial,

with full names (first, mid, last) > partial names (first, last)

example:

John < John Kennedy < J. F. K. < J. F. Kennedy < John F. Kennedy < John Fitzgerald Kennedy

So if my person object could be:

```
name_variant_1 = {
    first: "John",
    last: "Kennedy"
}

name_variant_2 = {
    first: "J.",
    mid: "F.",
    last: "K."
}
```

what is the best way to compare them for the better name?

I want to do this with the most efficient phrasing and not a lot of branching logic. I would prefer not to use a name scoring heuristic.

Thanks!!

Comment: Any reason why you explicitly prefer brevity over readability?

Comment: @IngoBürk: Because conciseness is very relevant here to show the hierarchy, instead of getting lost in branching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to do this with the most efficient phrasing and not a lot of branching logic.

Well, basically you *need* branching logic, but there are some ways to make it less painful. There are two tricks:

- `if (a && !b) return 1; else if (!a && b) return -1; else return 0;` can be simplified to `return a - b;`
- `if (a != 0) return a; else return b;` can be simplified to `return a || b;`

So you could formulate your comparison logic as

```
function hasFullName(x) {
    return ('first' in x) && ('mid' in x) && ('last' in x);
}
function isInitial(x) {
    return x.charAt(x.length - 1) == ".";
}
function comparePart(a, b) {
    return (!!a - !!b) // part exists at all?
        || (isInitial(b) - isInitial(a));
}

function compare(a, b) {
    return (hasFullName(a) - hasFullName(b)) // full names always win
        || comparePart(a.last, b.last)
        || comparePart(a.first, b.first)
        || comparePart(a.mid, b.mid);
}
```

Test:

```
> [{"first":"J.","mid":"F.","last":"K."},{"first":"J.","mid":"F.","last":"Kennedy"},{"first":"John","mid":"F.","last":"Kennedy"},{"first":"John","mid":"Fitzgerald","last":"Kennedy"},{"first":"John"},{"first":"John","last":"Kennedy"}]
> .sort(compare)
[{"first":"John"},{"first":"John","last":"Kennedy"},{"first":"J.","mid":"F.","last":"K."},{"first":"J.","mid":"F.","last":"Kennedy"},{"first":"John","mid":"F.","last":"Kennedy"},{"first":"John","mid":"Fitzgerald","last":"Kennedy"}]
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and what I'm looking for! 

Can you explain the rationale behind: 

if (a && !b) return 1; else if (!a && b) return -1; else return 0; can be simplified to return a - b;

What does a boolean - boolean do?

Comment: @Ninjack: It cast them to numbers (`true -> 1`, `false -> 0`) and then subtracts them.

Comment: what's your rule of thumb for knowing when to use this trick? I definitely would want to use it in the future. It's kinda like a weird XOR?

Comment: @Ninjack: Oh, I use it all the time. I mean, when you understand how it works (and it is in fact rather simple), you can judge yourself whether you have a rare case where you cannot use it.